Continuity of the set of critical points of a Morse function when the function varies
Let me first give the result I am looking for, then what I found up to now and some related questions.
Definition/Notation.
Denote $Y_k(f)$ the set of critical values $x$ of $f$ such that the index of $\operatorname{Hess}_x(f)$ is equal to $k$. Denote $W^{k,2}$ the Sobolev space with $L^2$ derivatives up to order $k$.
Objective.
Let $f\in C^2([0,1]^d)$ be a Morse function and $(f_n)_n$ be a sequence of functions in $C^2([0,1]^d)$ such that $f_n \to f$ with respect to the $W^{2,2}$-topology. Do we have $Y_k(f_n) \to Y_k(f)$ ?
Related literature.
On page 5 of this reference, there is this paragraph:

Notice that it follows that the number of critical points is a locally constant function. Also, as we vary $f$ in a small neighborhood the critical points vary continuously and Hessians at the critical point also vary continuously. Since the index is a discrete invariant of the Hessian, it is a locally constant function on the set of non-degenerate quadratic forms. Thus, for all Morse functions sufficiently close to $f$ we have a one-to-one correspondence of critical points preserving the indices.

Considering the context of this quote, I think that the expression "as we vary $f$ in a small neighborhood" implicitly means a neighborhood in $C_0^\infty(M;R)$ with respect to Whitney $C^\infty$-topology.
Related questions.

The above argument "the critical points vary continuously" does not seem trivial to me. At least, it does not seem to use the fact that the functions are Morse which is, as far as I understood, essential. Could you give me more insight about this argument ?
The subscript $0$ in $C_0^\infty(M;R)$ means that $f$ has no critical points on the boundary $\partial M$ and that $f$ is locally constant on $\partial M$. Does the continuity result still holds if we replace $C_0^\infty(M;R)$ by $C^\infty(M;R)$ ?
I expect that the continuity result still holds if we replace the $C^\infty$-topology by the $C^2$-topology. In other words, it would answer my objective at the cost of replacing the $W^{2,2}$-topology by the $C^2$-topology. Is my expectation correct ? Do you know a reference ?
Finally, do you think that my objective holds true ? I expect it to be false in general because the $W^{2,2}$-topology does not give a control of the index of the Hessian but I may be losing something.

Thank you very much in advance for your comment or answer.
